# beamer frametitle redefinition interferes with allowframebreaks option

Tags: beamer, frame-title

**The problem:** In beamer, when I use the `allowframebreaks` option, the title of the second (and succeeding) frames look like this: "[ II", "[ III" etc. The actual title is in the text below, like so: "Title]Title".

**The presumed cause:**
I'm using a colleague's beamer template, which I do not fully understand.
It might be a bit of a hack.
I've been able to locate the problem, however: `\frametitle` is being redefined in order to include the university logo.

This is an MWE (you need to provide a graphic `logo.*`):

```
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\newcommand{\MyLogoNeg}{%
\begin{textblock}{90}(12.7,0.09)
  \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo}
\end{textblock}
}

\let\oldframetitle\frametitle
\renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{\oldframetitle{#1}\MyLogoNeg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I include the logo without breaking `allowframebreaks`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\frametitle` can have an overlay specification as well as an optional argument: the complete syntax is (cf. the [`beamer` manual, section 8.2.6](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.8.2.6))

> `\frametitle<⟨overlay specification⟩>[⟨short frame title⟩]{⟨frame title text⟩}`

Redefining `\frametitle` with `\renewcommand` to just have one mandatory argument breaks the cases when one of these additional arguments is used (as is done internally by `beamer` when using the option `allowframebreaks`).

Instead of directly hacking `\frametitle`, consider adding your logo to the beamer template `frametitle`, which is a much more appropriate place for such modifications: to do this, replace

```
\let\oldframetitle\frametitle
\renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{\oldframetitle{#1}\MyLogoNeg}
```

by

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\MyLogoNeg}
```